# Play the default animation only after the previous one is completed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making an endless runner and i want the GameObject to jump once, when the up key is pressed. My problem is that as soon as I release the key the GameObject stops jumping and goes into its default animation of running without completing the jump animation. How can I get the GameObject to complete the animation once, and only then enter the running animation state. 
I am using animator where Running is default animation and Jump is on key press.

please help!

```
void moveNinja()
{
    if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) )
    {
        animator.SetBool("jump", true);
        animator.SetBool("run", false);
        animator.SetBool("slide", false);
    }
    if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)))
    {
        animator.SetBool("slide", true);
        animator.SetBool("run", false);
        animator.SetBool("jump", false);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S))
    {
        animator.SetBool("run", true);
        animator.SetBool("slide", false);
        animator.SetBool("jump", false);

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetBool("run", true);
        animator.SetBool("slide", false);
        animator.SetBool("jump", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the answer below helped? Please tick it to accept as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes good question.
Go to your animator, select the transition arrow that goes back from jump to run state and add Exit Time condition in your inspector. That way transition will only happen when all bools are correct and Animation clip finished.

Screenshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: was breaking my head over this with code. Thanks a ton

Comment: Your welcome. by using this you should have nice animation flow in animator